# protractor cannot find className

Tags: angular, protractor

I am wanting to select object by className and NOT css or id and i continuely get error, cannot locate css selector, even though im trying to select with className. Even said i can not get the element with the css either. I have just set up protractor, so maybe im missing something?  protractor - Version 5.3.0, and i run the test file using 'ng e2e' from command line.

this is my page object:

```
   import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('https://mywebsite.com');       
  }

  getSearchBtn() {
    return element(by.className('c-search-form-button'));
```

and this is my spec file

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import {Config} from 'protractor';

  describe('playground', () => {
    let page: AppPage;
  ;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);  // must have if non-angular site  
    page.navigateTo();   // or browser.get(url);  //or browser.get('https://website.com');

  });

   it('click the search button', () => {
    page.getSearchBtn().click();

  });

});
```

error

```
- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .c-search-form-button)
```

the object

```
<div class="c-search-form"> 
<push-button class="c-search-form-button">
...
</push-button>
```

i have also tried with

```
element(by.className('c-search-form')); 
element(by.className('c-search-form-button')); 
element(by.css('.c-search-form-button')); 
element(by.css('.c-search-form'));
element(by.tagName('push-button'));
```

Comment: not enough information to reproduce... see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this class 'c-search-submit-button' actually exist in your code? I could imagine that bodiless classes are ignored by CSS and so are invisible to protractor... The code itself looks good.

Comment: There has to be more this. I copied your code exactly as is and it is giving me an `Element is not clickable at point (x, y)` message. When I added a `button` inside the div the test turned green. Your code seems to be ok. There is something else going on causing the failure. Are you sure you are navigating to the correct page before attempting to click the button?

Comment: i have updated my example with more code. Any pointers please as to where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Try add some sleep `browser.sleep(15*1000) // 15 secs` before `page.getSearchBtn().click()`. And if the element inside frame,  you need to switch to the frame firstly.

Comment: browser.sleep(2*1000)  worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apply wait for elment presence/ visbile before execute to this element.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with class 'c-search-form-button' to be visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('.c-search-form-button')), 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, so i found this solution:
this is my function to analyze if a material checkbox is checked or not:

PARAMS:

- box: element finder, father of material `mat-checkbox` (in example, the seg-checkbox element);
- boxname: name to pass just for log error if can't find it;
- checked: if passed as `false`, analyze if checkbox is NOT checked.

```js
export async function checkCheckBoxChecked(box: ElementFinder, boxname: string, checked?: any) {
  if (checked === false) {
    try {
      zzz(2000);
      const check = await box.element(by.xpath('./mat-checkbox'));
      const cls = await check.getAttribute('class');
      expect(cls + ' - ' + boxname).not.toMatch('mat-checkbox-checked - ' + boxname);
    } catch (e) {
      expect('not found element ' + boxname).toEqual('!!!');
    };
  } else {
    try {
      zzz(2000);
      const check = await box.element(by.xpath('./mat-checkbox'));
      const cls = await check.getAttribute('class');
      expect(cls + ' - ' + boxname).toMatch('mat-checkbox-checked - ' + boxname);
    } catch (e) {
      expect('not found element ' + boxname).toEqual('!!!');
    };
  }
};
```

HTML file

```html
<seg-checkbox _ngcontent-c39="" align="start" name="flagInfo" _nghost-c38="" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-empty">
  <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-c38="" class="mat-checkbox mat-accent mat-checkbox-anim-checked-unchecked" id="mat-checkbox-2">
...
  </mat-checkbox>
</seg-checkbox>
```

Everything is done with `getAttribute('class')`;

- PS: the `zzz(2000)` simply do `browser.sleep(2000)`;
- PPS: sometimes `expect(cls + ' - ' + boxname).toMatch('mat-checkbox-checked - ' + boxname);` doesn't work properly, so you can simply use: `expect(cls).toMatch('mat-checkbox-checked);`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I first started with protractor. I tried different wait statements, visibilityof etc. None have worked for me. Somewhere I heard that if the element you are looking is not completely visible in the browser then this can happen not to find the element. All I did was added the browser capabilities in my config as follows to make my browser max size. Then it started working as a charm. Not sure but this might help in your case if you haven't tried yet.

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
 args: ['start-fullscreen','show-fps-counter=true']
}
```